# How to detect a value change on an input when it is dynamically updated (Angular 6)

Tags: angular

I'm using a custom directive and custom pipe to do currency formatting on text inputs. It works fine with any kind of direct user input (focus, blur, keydown). However I can't seem to capture the change event when the value is changed dynamically. I also can't find a reliable list of hostlistener events, and don't know of a way to capture any event coming to the input (and thus can't see what event, if any, is happening).

Dynamically, the value is being set with patchValue, and I've set emitEvent to true but this appears to do nothing (I assume it's true by default anyway):

```
myInput.patchValue({content: currentContent}, { emitEvent: true });
```

I could rewrite the currency formatting before the content value is set with patchValue, but this goes against reusability.

Here is my directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '../pipes/currency.pipe';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appCurrency]'
})
export class CurrencyDirective implements OnInit {

constructor(
    private elementRef:ElementRef,
    private formatcurrencypipe:CurrencyPipe
) { }

ngOnInit(){
    //this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = this.formatcurrencypipe.transform(this.elementRef.nativeElement.value);
}

@HostListener("change", ["$event.target.value", "$event"]) onChange(value, event) {
    //this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = this.formatcurrencypipe.parse(value);
}

@HostListener("valueChange", ["$event.target.value", "$event"]) onValueChange(value, event) {
    console.log('in onValueChange');
    //doesn't trigger when the value is changed dynamically
}

@HostListener("focus",["$event.target.value","$event"]) onFocus(value,event) {
    console.log('in focus');
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = this.formatcurrencypipe.parse(value);
    if(event.which == 9)
    {
        return false;
    }
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.select();
}

@HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"]) onBlur(value) {
    console.log('in blur');
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = this.formatcurrencypipe.transform(value);
}

@HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
    let e = <KeyboardEvent> event;
    console.log('e.keyCode: ', e.keyCode, e.ctrlKey, e.metaKey);
    //delete, backspace, tab, escape, enter, decimal, period, arrow left, arrow right
    if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190, 37, 39].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1
    || (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) //CTRL + A
    || (e.keyCode === 67 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) //CTRL + C
    || (e.keyCode === 86 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) //CTRL + V
    || (e.keyCode === 88 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey))) {  //CTRL + X
        //do nothing
        return;
    }

    // Check for number
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
}
```

I've added the stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tys9cy

Comment: have you tried <input class="name" (change)="onChange($event)"> ?

Comment: Just tried it and that doesn't do anything either. I may not have the correct event in hostlistener to capture it.

Comment: In your directive you're method is right `@HostListener("change", ["$event.target.value", "$event"]) onChange(value, event) {}`. In your pipe you should put the transformations in `transform()` method, it changes automatically.

Comment: The transformations are in the `transform()` method, but whatever event is happening when the value is dynamically changed is not being captured by hostlistener. I don't know if it has something to do with patchValue.

Comment: can you create a stackbliz please?

Comment: I don't know what a stackbliz is but I will do some googling. (I may not be able to, as this is part of a larger project).

Comment: I've added the stackblitz.

Comment: @KatharineOsborne [Forked StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g8zsmt) Have a look

Comment: Yup that definitely works, but I won't necessarily want to set the focus on the input (this could be an accessibility issue for instance; popping the focus where it's not expected, and I'm not sure how that would work when there are multiple inputs involved). I suppose blur though is more appropriate.

Comment: @KatharineOsborne `patchValue` emits  `valueChange` event that's why directive is not picking up the changes

Comment: `Hostlistener` is not picking up the `valueChange` event. I've updated the stackblitz (sorry it wasn't included initially).

Comment: @KatharineOsborne Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reactive form instances like `FormGroup` and `FormControl` have a `valueChanges` method that returns an `observable` that emits the latest values. It does not emit a DOM event.
**Solution**

Instead of `valueChange` bind to `ngModelChange` that will be triggered on both events i.e. when formControl is updated in View or via Model.

```
@HostListener("ngModelChange", [ "$event"]) onNgModelChange(value) {
         console.log(value)
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = this.formatcurrencypipe.transform(value);
}
```

[`Working StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g8zsmt)

Comment: `ngModelChange` is firing after keydown so you can't type more than one key before it transforms again.

Comment: @KatharineOsborne you can use Rxjs [debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html) for it give it a try if you are not able to figure out the solution I will help u out

Comment: Yeah I can't figure out how to use debounceTime. I'm not sure it's appropriate either as the user may pause before finishing typing (there's a lot of mental math they may need to do in the context of the project). I set a data value to capture the focus state, and while it's doing that, I can no longer apply the pipe correctly. Anyway, it feels very un-angular.

Comment: OMG I just realised I had set my focus flag to true on blur as well as on focus *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Based on @vikas answer, I modified so that it only updates with `ngModelChange` when the value is dynamically set and not also when the user is editing (as `ngModelChange` is too inclusive for what I need):

```
@HostListener("ngModelChange", [ "$event"]) onNgModelChange(value) {
    //when value changes dynamically
    if (this.elementRef.nativeElement.dataset.isfocused == 'false') {
        console.log('is not focused');
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = this.formatcurrencypipe.transform(value);
    } else {
        console.log('is focused');
    }
}

@HostListener("focus",["$event.target.value","$event"]) onFocus(value,event) {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.dataset.isfocused = true;
    console.log('isfocused: ', this.elementRef.nativeElement.dataset);
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = this.formatcurrencypipe.parse(value);
    if(event.which == 9)
    {
        return false;
    }
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.select();
}

@HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"]) onBlur(value) {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.dataset.isfocused = false;
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = this.formatcurrencypipe.transform(value);
}
```

And the input:

```
<input appCurrency data-isfocused="false" type="text" class="form-control number" formControlName="myInput" />
```

It seems horridly un-angular to use a data-attribute :-(